# PHP JSON If or Else

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to write a PHP script so if the network type is a JSON feed, I'm pulling indicates mobile event is triggered and if not another event is triggered. I can't figure out the if or else, I've tried a bunch of variations.

Code:

```
echo( "Network Type: " . $decoded_response['current_carrier']['network_type']); 
if ($decoded_response['current_carrier']['network_type']) = 'mobile') {
    echo "Event1"; 
} else {
    echo "Event2";
}
```

Comment: `=` -> `==` assign vs comparison

Comment: single = in your if, thats an assignment no a comparison! ==

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL)

Comment: That's with the ==

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra `)` in your if statement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($decoded_response['current_carrier']['network_type']) = 'mobile'){
```

maybe this should be

```
if ($decoded_response['current_carrier']['network_type'] == 'mobile'){
```

You are using single `=` instead of `==` to check for equality. `=` would assign and not test.